# Inlining functions in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, inline

I'm looking for a way to inline functions in AS3.

I know that the language itself doesn't offer a native way of doing that but perhaps there is another option:

- ANT precompile task
- shell script
- command line tool
- ...

Basically, anything that could eventually be integrated with ANT and run on a Hudson CI server.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? We run ANT on Hudson to build our Flash projects but there's no need for any AS3 wizardry there.

Comment: @frankhermes: The problem is that there's no native way in AS3 to inline certain functions. So you have to choose between a) tidy code with countless slow function calls or b) fast code with tiny bits of instructions copy-pasted all over the place. One of our devs I talked to today made the suggestion of writing some sort of macro or ANT task to accomplish inlining on a source code level before compiling, so I was curious if something similar had already been done.

Comment: Is the code pure math or is it doing something with display objects?

Comment: @The_asMan: I'm not personally involved with the project that requested this feature from my team, but I think it's primarily about math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Joa Ebert](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/) [Apparat](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/) tools to achieve such a thing and more.
You can't inline whatever function you want they are some [restrictions](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/wiki/MacroExpansion)

Basically you have to create a new class that extends Macro or Inlined following your need, and declare static function within it, then after running [TDSI](http://labs.exoa.fr/tuto-as3-apparat-tdsi-accelerez-vos-projets/) your function will be inlined.

Check out for example [Math inlined function](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/source/browse/apparat-ersatz/src/main/as3/apparat/math/IntMath.as) or [Macro function](http://code.google.com/p/apparat/source/browse/apparat-ersatz/src/main/as3/apparat/math/MathMacro.as)

Comment: Wow, a very nice and very impressive tool!

Comment: You Patrick my friend are a hero. This improved performance in some of my code that uses functions for readability and to prevent Duplicate code about 6 times faster.

Comment: You're welcome, the next compiler (still in beta) ASC2 can now afford some inlining too , more on that here : http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4789

Answer (score 3):

Adobe introduced native inline functions with the new ASC2 compiler in 2012. Use the -inline compiler argument to inline all getters and setters and any functions marked with the new [Inline] metadata. Inlined functions must meet these conditions:

- The function is final, static or the containing scope is file or package
- The function does not contain any activations
- The function does not contain any try or with statements
- The function does not contain any function closures
- The function body contains less than 50 expressions

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=4789